# Having trouble in getting data using css selector/xpath in selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to extract data from the link below using selenium via python:
[www.oanda.com](https://www.oanda.com/forex-trading/analysis/open-position-ratios)

But I'm getting an error that, "Unable to Locate an Element". In browser console i tried using this Css selector:

```
document.querySelector('div.position.short-position.style-scope.position-ratios-app')
```

This querySelector returns me the data for short percentage of 1st row in the browser console(for this test), but when i used this selector in the python script below it gives me an error that, "Unable to Locate element" or sometimes empty sctring.
Please suggest me solution if there's any.Will be grateful, thanks :)

```
# All Imports
import time
from selenium import webdriver

#will return driver
def getDriver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    time.sleep(3)
    return driver


def getshortPercentages(driver):
    shortPercentages = []
    shortList = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.position.short-position.style-scope.position-ratios-app')
    for elem in shortList:
        shortPercentages.append(elem.text)
    return shortPercentages

def getData(url):
    driver = getDriver()
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    # pagesource = driver.page_source
    # print("Page Source: ", pagesource)
    shortList = getshortPercentages(driver)
    print("Returned source from selector: ", shortList)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://www.oanda.com/forex-trading/analysis/open-position-ratios"
    getData(url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Required data is located inside an iframe, so you need to switch to iframe before handling elements:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_class_name('position-ratios-iframe'))
```

Also note that data inside iframe is dynamic, so make sure that you're using [*Implicit/Explicit wait*](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) (using `time.sleep(5)` IMHO is not the best solution)

Comment: thanks it's working. was working on that from recent 4hours and you save my day. Many thanks.